# linux bonding - changing params if statically linked

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, bonding

I want to run some tests using linux network bonding. I am using qemu VMs and I am using a custom-built kernel to run them where I set it up to have bonding statically linked. I see in the documentation that it's possible to set up parameters for bonding (like miimon) when loading the module. But how can these values be set when it's statically linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two APIs to handle bonding interfaces, *in addition* to the obsolete commands (on Linux) `ifconfig` and `ifenslave`, which probably aren't able to create a new bond interfaces (and thus require the bonding module's `max_bonds` parameter to be non zero).

- kernel's ([rt](https://manpages.debian.org/rtnetlink.7))[netlink API](https://manpages.debian.org/netlink.7): through most of the modern commands provided by *iproute2* including the `ip link` command.
- kernel's *sysfs* API via pseudo-files: usually mounted in `/sys/`.

I can note that "recent" versions of `ifenslave` actually rely on the the *sysfs* API and a little on the *rtnetlink* API through `ip link`.

You should probably configure bonding to create zero interface instead of the default one or two: this is an historical feature that became obsolete with these two APIs. These interface can be created or removed dynamically later. Of course for a very minimal system leaving it or setting it to create the required needed number is still an option. Adding this to the kernel command line options (usually found in `/etc/default/grub`'s `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` entry, but doing this correctly might depend on the distribution) should do it:

```
bonding.max_bonds=0
```

- [Configuring Bonding Manually with iproute2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.rst?h=v5.10#n1302) (`ip link`):

  Warning: the linked documentation is quite incomplete/obsolete and doesn't show that most if not all of the bonding features are available through `ip link`.

  You can create delete alter settings enslave etc. with the right `ip link` command. This command should include the keywords `type bond` whenever it has to specify a specific *bond* option after them.

  command syntax reminder, to display specific *bond* settings:

  ```
  ip link add type bond help
  ```

  example (interfaces must be down before being enslaved, but can be set such in the same single command in case former state is not known):

  ```
  ip link add dev mybond0 type bond mode active-backup miimon 100
  ip link set dev eth0 down master mybond0
  ip link set dev eth1 down master mybond0
  ip link set dev mybond0 up
  ip link set dev eth0 up
  ip link set dev eth1 up
  ```

  changing settings:

  ```
  ip link set dev mybond0 type bond miimon 200
  ```

  `ifenslave` equivalent:

  ```
  ip link set dev mybond0 type bond active_slave eth1
  ```

  some settings can't be changed while there are any enslaved devices. Eg, redefining the bond type:

  ```
  # ip link set dev mybond0 type bond mode balance-rr
  RTNETLINK answers: Directory not empty
  ```

  enslaved devices can be set free with:

  ```
  ip link set dev eth0 nomaster
  ```

  and the bond device can be deleted with:

  ```
  ip link delete dev mybond0
  ```

  various information related to a *bond* device (or to a *bond_slave* device) can be seen with the additional `-details` option. At some point using JSON output can be easier for scripts (eg, this Q/A: [iproute2: How to display the TYPE of a network devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616157/iproute2-how-to-display-the-type-of-a-network-devices)).

  ```
  ip -detail link show dev mybond0
  ip -detail link show dev eth0
  ip -detail link show dev eth1
  ```
- [Configuring Bonding Manually via Sysfs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.rst?h=v5.10#n1419)

  I don't think using this API makes much sense today unless a specific feature wasn't made available through `ip link`. It was probably created before *iproute2* tools could handle all of it. Maybe reading from it could still help in case the tools on a restricted/embedded system don't have anymore access to an `ip link` command, but even this seems unlikely.

  As described in the linked documentation, you can create and delete bonding interfaces through `/sys/class/net/bonding_masters` which is present whenever the bonding module is present (here as built-in).

  Here are the equivalent commands from above, simply using `echo ... > ...` from a root shell (or having to work around redirections with `sudo echo ... | tee ...`):

  ```
  echo +mybond0 > /sys/class/net/bonding_masters
  echo active-backup > /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/mode
  echo 100 > /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/miimon
  ```

  I don't see any way to set interfaces up or down through *sysfs* anyway. To stay safe:

  ```
  ip link set dev eth0 down
  ip link set dev eth1 down

  echo +eth0 > /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/slaves
  echo +eth1 > /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/slaves
  ```

  Again, there's no other way:

  ```
  ip link set dev mybond0 up
  ip link set dev eth0 up
  ip link set dev eth1 up
  ```

  Then continuing like the previous example:

  ```
  echo 200 > /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/miimon
  echo eth1 > /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/active_slave

  # echo balance-rr > /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/mode
  bash: echo: write error: Directory not empty

  echo -eth0 > /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/slaves
  echo -mybond0 > /sys/class/net/bonding_masters
  ```

  Specific *bonding* information is available there:

  ```
  cat /sys/class/net/bonding_masters
  grep ^ /sys/class/net/mybond0/bonding/*
  grep ^ /sys/class/net/eth0/bonding_slave/*
  grep ^ /sys/class/net/eth1/bonding_slave/*
  ```

Comment: It seems to be working fine through iproute2.